# Примеры разработок на kohana 3.x

Tags: cms, kohana

Добрый день. Интересует цикл статей по разработке какой-то системы, например, CMS на kohana 3.х. Может, кто-то что-то видел. Подскажите, где такое можно посмотреть и увидеть правильный стиль проектирования и более-менее чётное описание, как нужно проектировать системы на kohana. Пытался найти уже готовую CMS и разбирать её, чтобы посмотреть, как всё реализовано, но находил лишь примеры на старых версиях. Да, есть конечно статьи на хабре и не только, где есть описание и примеры кода, но я лишь находил относительно работы какого-то модуля. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

1. Прочитайте про HMVC
2. Почитайте мануалы по Кохане.

А вообще, там всё просто. Сам люблю этот фреймворк и делаю сейчас проекты на нём.

Answer (score 1):

Я потихоньку свою cms клепаю сайт http://cmspegas.ru
Код может не вершина мастерства ,делаю для себя ,да и пишу по ним уроки )